# How can I find my CNAME or TXT DNS record in google sites to give to my custom domain DNS Record

Tags: dns

I created website through google sites.  I have purchased a custom domain from domain.com and am trying to get them to talk to each other.  However, when I put in my CNAME DNS Record it didn't talk.  I deleted it and am trying to connect it again but I can't find the CNAME record now.

I have tried to watch youtube videos and look at google support but can't seem to find my answer.